# 2D game algorithm to calculate a bullet's needed speed to hit target?

Tags: javascript, math, graphics, geometry, 2d

I have a rather simple bird's-view 2D game where tower sprites defend against incoming moving sprites by shooting a bullet at them. My question: How do I calculate the needed bullet speed for the bullet to reach its moving target, provided that the bullet will always have the same defined speed?

I'm using JavaScript and have these sprite variables (among others):
sprite.x, sprite.y, sprite.width, sprite.height, sprite.speedX (i.e. velocity), sprite.speedY... so I have the objects originSprite, targetSprite and bulletSprite, all with these type of values, and I need to set the right bulletSprite speed values.

Probably for it to look good, the bullet would start at the outside of the originSprite (or some defined radius, though I guess starting from the originSprite center would also work), but its bullet center would try hit into the center of the targetSprite or so. Note there's no gravity or anything in this world. (Perhaps I should have my sprites variables using angle and velocity but right now I'm using speedX and speedY...)

Thanks so much!

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you give an example?

Comment: Are we talking about a tower defense clone in which the incoming targets may turn around corners while the bullet is in flight, or is it a given that targets will move in a straight line?

Comment: Sjoerd, to given an example, there will be a static sprite, let's call it the shooter, and an incoming moving sprite, let's call it a mover. The shooter has a certain distance at which it starts seeing the enemy mover, and it "knows" the enemy's speed, and it then tries to fire a shot. The shooter's bullets are always at constant speed, so if say the shooter is exactly below the mover, and the mover is moving downwards, the bullet.speedX would be 0 and the bullet.speedY would be -1.

Comment: Deceze, the tower will always assume that the targets will move in a straight line and at a constant speed (the targets may actually rarely bump off somewhere and change direction but the tower won't calculate this or "know" this, i.e. the tower may well miss its target in border cases but that's OK).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [vectors](http://physics.about.com/od/mathematics/a/VectorMath_2.htm) can make the math around this seem a little simpler.  [Sylvester](http://sylvester.jcoglan.com/) seems to be a promising implementation of vectors in JavaScript, but for the purpose of my example, I'll write my own vector functions.  I'm also going to assume `.x` / `.y` are measured top/left corner.

```
// this is a "constant"  - representing 10px motion per "time unit"
var bulletSpeed = 10; 
// calculate the vector from our center to their center
var enemyVec = vec_sub(targetSprite.getCenter(), originSprite.getCenter());
// measure the "distance" the bullet will travel
var dist = vec_mag(enemyVec);
// adjust for target position based on the amount of "time units" to travel "dist"
// and the targets speed vector
enemyVec = vec_add(enemyVec, vec_mul(targetSprite.getSpeed(), dist/bulletSpeed));
// calculate trajectory of bullet
var bulletTrajectory = vec_mul(vec_normal(enemyVec), bulletSpeed);
// assign values
bulletSprite.speedX = bulletTrajectory.x;  
bulletSprite.speedY = bulletTrajectory.y;  

// functions used in the above example:

// getCenter and getSpeed return "vectors"
sprite.prototype.getCenter = function() { 
  return {
    x: this.x+(this.width/2), 
    y: this.y+(this.height/2) 
  }; 
};

sprite.prototype.getSpeed = function() { 
  return {
    x: this.speedX, 
    y: this.speedY 
  }; 
};

function vec_mag(vec) { // get the magnitude of the vector
  return Math.sqrt( vec.x * vec.x + vec.y * vec.y); 
 }
function vec_sub(a,b) { // subtract two vectors
  return { x: a.x-b.x, y: a.y-b.y };
}
function vec_add(a,b) { // add two vectors
  return { x: a.x + b.x, y: a.y + b.y };
}
function vec_mul(a,c) { // multiply a vector by a scalar
  return { x: a.x * c, y: a.y * c };
}
function vec_div(a,c) { // divide == multiply by 1/c
  return vec_mul(a, 1.0/c);
}
function vec_normal(a) { // normalize vector
  return vec_div(a, vec_mag(a)); 
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. (A note for others copying this, in one place you need to amend veg_mag into vec_mag.) I had to dabble around a bit with finding the right bulletSpeed value and then the bullets hit their moving targets spot on. Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

Treat the targets sprite as a straight line in a 2 dimensional room where:

```
A(time) = (sprite.positionX + sprite.speedX * time, sprite.positionX + sprite.speedX * time)
```

As your bullet have constant speed you also know:

```
bullet.speedX^2 + bullet.speedY^2 = bullet.definedSpeed^2
```

Then you can also calculate a straight line for the bullet:

```
B(time) = (bullet.positionX + bullet.speedX * time, bullet.positionX + bullet.speedX * time)
```

And you know that both lines interset somewhere:

```
A(time) = B(time)
```

Then it's up to you to solve those equations with your given values and seek a minimum for `time`.

Comment: If solving the system of linear equations is consuming too much CPU time when you are doing this in real-time (which it might, depending on how many bullets are in flight at the same time), you can probably pre-compute a set of solutions and only solve the corner cases in real-time.  Assuming your targets will move with a known speed, calculate a result based on (say) eight different directions that they could approach from (N,NE,E,etc).  When the shooter detects a target, simply look up whether you have a result pre-computed for a target with that speed and bearing.  If not, calculate it.

Comment: @bta: Of course it makes sense to solve those equations on paper by treating those the known variables as constants before one goes to write code.

Answer (score 5):

## Some physical insight

### 1 ) For the target being a "Point Object"

So you have to solve the VECTOR equation

**Position<sub>bullet</sub> [ time=t<sub>1</sub> > t<sub>0</sub> ] == Position<sub>target</sub> [ time=t<sub>1</sub> > t<sub>0</sub> ]    -- (Eq 1)**

Where the positions are given by the motion (also VECTOR) equations

**Position<sub>object</sub> [ t ] = Position<sub>object</sub> [ t<sub>0</sub> ] + Speed<sub>object</sub> *  ( t - t<sub>0</sub> )**

Now, the condition for the bullet to be able to reach the target is that the Eq 1 has solutions for x and y. Let's write down the equation for x:

**X<sub>bullet</sub> [ t<sub>0</sub> ] + SpeedX<sub>bullet</sub> * ( t - t<sub>0</sub> )  = X<sub>target</sub> [ t<sub>0</sub> ] + SpeedX<sub>target</sub> * ( t - t<sub>0</sub> )**

So for the collision time we have

**( t<sub>Collision</sub> - t<sub>0</sub> )  =  (x<sub>target</sub> [ t <sub>0</sub> ] - x<sub>bullet</sub> [ t<sub>0</sub> ] ) / (SpeedX<sub>bullet</sub> - SpeedX<sub>target</sub>) -- (Eq 2)**

As we need solutions with t > t<sub>0</sub>, that means that for having an intercept is enough that>

**Sign ( x<sub>target</sub>[ t<sub>0</sub> ]  - x<sub>bullet</sub>[ t<sub>0</sub> ] ) = Sign ( SpeedX<sub>bullet</sub> - SpeedX<sub>target</sub> )  --  (Eq 3)**

`Which tells us the evident fact that if an object is moving faster than the other, and in the same direction, they will eventually collide.`

From Eq 2, you can see that for a given SpeedX<sub>target</sub> **there exist infinite solutions** (as already pointed out in other answers) for t and SpeedX<sub>bullet</sub>, so I think your specifications are not complete.

`I guess (as stated in a commentary I made in another answer) thinking in a "tower defense" kind of game, that your bullets have a limited range.`

So you need also another constraint:

**Distance [ Position<sub>target</sub> [ t<sub>Collision</sub> - t<sub>0</sub> ] -  Position<sub>bullet</sub> [ t<sub>0</sub> ] ] < BulletRange  -- (Eq 4)**

`Which still permits infinite solutions, but bounded by an upper value for the Collision time, given by the fact that the target may abandon the range.`

Further, the distance is given by

Distance[v,u]= +Sqrt[ (Vx-Ux)^2 + (Vx-Vy)^2 ]

So, Eq 4 becomes,

**(X<sub>target</sub>[t<sub>Collision</sub> - t<sub>0</sub>] - X<sub>bullet</sub>[t<sub>0</sub>])<sup>2</sup> + (Y<sub>target</sub>[t<sub>Collision</sub> - t<sub>0</sub>] - Y<sub>bullet</sub>[t<sub>0</sub>])<sup>2</sup> < BulletRange<sup>2</sup> -- (Eq 5)**

Note that { X<sub>bullet</sub>[t<sub>0</sub>] , Y<sub>bullet</sub>[t<sub>0</sub>} is the tower position.

Now, replacing in Eq 5 the values for the target position:

**(X<sub>target</sub>[t<sub>0</sub>] + SpeedX<sub>target</sub> * (t-t<sub>0</sub>) - X<sub>bullet</sub>[t<sub>0</sub>])<sup>2</sup> + (Y<sub>target</sub>[t<sub>0</sub>] + SpeedY<sub>target</sub> * (t-t<sub>0</sub>) - Y<sub>bullet</sub>[t<sub>0</sub>])<sup>2</sup>  <  BulletRange<sup>2</sup>  -- (Eq 6)**

Calling the initial distances:

Dxt0 = X<sub>target</sub>[t<sub>0</sub>] - X<sub>bullet</sub>[t<sub>0</sub>]

and

**Dyt0 = Y<sub>target</sub>[t<sub>0</sub>] - Y<sub>bullet</sub>[t<sub>0</sub>]**

Equation 6 becomes

**(Dtx0 + SpeedX<sub>target</sub> * (t-t<sub>0</sub>) )<sup>2</sup> + (Dty0 + SpeedY<sub>target</sub> * (t-t<sub>0</sub>))<sup>2</sup>  <  BulletRange<sup>2</sup>  -- (Eq 7)**

Which is a quadratic equation to be solved in t-t0. The positive solution will give us the largest time allowed for the collision. Afterwards the target will be out of range.

Now calling

Speed<sub>target</sub> <sup>2</sup> = SpeedX<sub>target</sub> <sup>2</sup> + SpeedY<sub>target</sub> <sup>2</sup>

and

H = Dtx0 * SpeedX<sub>target</sub>  + Dty0 *  SpeedY<sub>target</sub>

**T<sub>Collision Max</sub> =  t<sub>0</sub> - ( H
 +/- Sqrt ( BulletRange<sup>2</sup> * Speed<sub>target</sub> <sup>2</sup> - H<sup>2</sup> ) ) / Speed<sub>target</sub> <sup>2</sup>**

`So you need to produce the collision BEFORE this time. The sign of the 
    square root should be taken such as the time is greater than t0`

```
After you select an appropriate flying time for your bullet from the visual 
effects point of view, you can calculate the SpeedX and SpeedY for the bullet 
from
```

**SpeedX<sub>bullet</sub> = ( X<sub>target</sub> [ t<sub>0</sub> ] - X<sub>bullet</sub> [ t<sub>0</sub> ] ) / ( t<sub>Collision</sub> -  t<sub>0</sub> ) + SpeedX<sub>target</sub>**

and

**SpeedY<sub>bullet</sub> = ( Y<sub>target</sub> [ t<sub>0</sub> ] - Y<sub>bullet</sub> [ t<sub>0</sub> ] ) / ( t<sub>Collision</sub> -  t<sub>0</sub> ) + SpeedY<sub>target</sub>**

### 2 ) For the target and tower being  "Extensive Objects"

Now, it is trivial to generalize for the case of the target being a circle of radius R. What you get, is the equivalent of an "extended range" for the bullets. That extension is just R.

So, replacing BulletRange by (BulletRange + R) you get the new equations for the maximum allowed collision time.

If you also want to consider a radius for the cannons, the same considerations apply, giving a "double extended range

**NewBulletRange  = BulletRange + R<sub>Target</sub> + R<sub>Tower</sub>**

### Unlimited Range Bullets

In the case that you decide that some special bullets should not have range (and detection) limitations, there is still the screen border constraint. But it is a little more difficult to tackle. Should you need this kind of projectile, leave a comment and I'll try to do some math.

Answer (score 1):

Compute the distance between shooter and target: `dist = sqrt((xt - xs)^2 + (yt - ys)^2)`
Divide the x and y distances by the above one: `nx = (xt - xs)/dist; ny = (yt - ys)/dist;` (normalization of the vector)
Multiply the results by a factor to get n pixels per time unit, ie. a speed in each direction. It should give a constant speed in the wanted direction.

Comment: This doesn't take into account the speed of the target at all and will therefore miss unless the target is moving directly towards or away from the shooter.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the target will move on a straight line with constant velocity.

If both the direction *and* the speed of the bullet are variable (i.e. you try to calculation `speedX` and `speedY` for the bullet), there are infinitely many solutions.

If you set a fixed direction, you simply intersect the two lines of the bullet and the target. From the distance between the current point of the target and the intersection point (and the target's speed) you can calculate the time the target will take to reach this intersection point.

From the distance between the origin of the bullet and the intersection point (and the previously calculated time) you can calculate the speed of the bullet.

Comment: something is missing in the specification. I guess that it is the RANGE of the bullets. If the OP specifies a RANGE, then the number of solutions is also infinite, but there will be a MINIMUM speed for the bullet (ie that one that intersects the bullet and target at that RANGE)